# How to convert a hexagonal unit cell to rhombohedral unit cell?

Tags: structure

Hexagonal unit cells can be converted to rhombohedral unit cells, and the latter unit cells have fewer atoms. But how can I convert them? Is there any software or codes that are able to do this transformation? For example, Cr2O3 has 30 atoms in the hexagonal unit cell, but can also be represented by 10 atoms in a rhombohedral unit cell.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [VESTA](https://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/) package should be able to do it. But I'm not sure if it had rhombohedral or not. I recommend that you download and try `Edit data -> Unit cell` option. You should be able to find enough tutorials doing this.
Alternatively, the [Quantum ATK](https://docs.quantumatk.com/index.html) package can handle the job. Refer to the [Tutorial](https://docs.quantumatk.com/tutorials/rhombo_hex_trigonal/rhombo_hex_trigonal.html).